# Tomcat responding success to load balancer port check before war files deployed

Tags: java, tomcat, port, load-balancing

I have 3 Tomcat servers under a Load Balancer. Each of these servers have the same 3 war files. The Load balancer checks the health of the Tomcat server by checking if Tomcat is listening to port 8080, if it receives a successful response, routes the traffic to that Tomcat server.

Now issue is that when Tomcat is starting up, it responds success to the Load balancer port check, even before all the war files are deployed. So initial requests routed to the Tomcat Server result in 404 because the application has not yet been deployed.

Is there a way I can prevent Tomcat from responding success to Load balancer port check until after all the web applications have been deployed?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using a TCP-based check? If so, make the load balancer check/monitor more intelligent, i.e. use a HTTP-based monitor that actually checks that HTTP responses are valid.

Comment: Yes it's a TCP based check. If Tomcat configuration does not work, my alternate solution was to implement a health check on the web applications itself that the Load balancer can poll. But it seemed an overkill to me.

Comment: All you need on the web app is a URL that responds to the LB monitor. This can be the front page, a dedicated health check page or whatever you see most fit.

Comment: Thanks. I think if the Tomcat configuration does not work, I'll have to do just that.